# Scramble the pixels of black and white images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, scramble

I have a series of black and white images (not greyscale, black and white; 2D matrices in Matlab), and I need to randomly scramble the pixels. I found this package in Mathworks File Exchange (https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66472-image-shuffle); one of the functions, *imScrambleRand*, does exactly what I need, but it works for RGB images (3D matrices). Is there a way to transform b&w images into 3D matrices so that I can use that function? Or can anyone suggest any other script that does what I need? Keep in mind that I'm not familiar with Matlab, but I'll do my best.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** When I import the BW image I get a 2D matrix of logic values (0 = black, 1 = white). I think the different data format (logic vs integer) is what yields errors when using the function for RGB images.

**EDIT 2:** I adapted the demo code from the aforementioned package and I used the suggestion by @Jonathan for transforming a 2D matrix into a 3D matrix, and added a loop to transform the logic values into RGB integer values, then use the *imScrambleRand* function. It works, but what I obtain is the following image: [SCRAMBLED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inLBv.png). This is the BW picture I start with: [BW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lEci.png). So I checked the scrambled image, and the function from the FEX file actually scrambles **within** the RGB values, meaning that I found, for instance, a pixel with [RGB 0,255,0](http://rgb.to/rgb/0,255,0). So I solved a problem but actually there's a problem within the function: it doesn't scramble pixels, it scrambles values generating colors that were not in the original picture.

**EDIT 3:** I used the code provided by @nhowe and I obtain exactly what I need, thanks!

**EDIT 4:** Ok, turns out it's not ok to scramble the pixels since it makes the image too scattered and different from the starting image (you don't say?), but I need to scramble **BLOCKS OF PIXELS** so that you can't really recognize the image but the black pixels are not too scattered. Is there a way to do that using the code provided by @nhowe?

**EDIT 5:** It should be ok with this function: https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56160-hio-been-hb-imagescramble

Comment: Grayscale are 2D matrices. BW refers to grayscale images with only 2 values.

Comment: @AnderBiguri When I import a BW image I obtain a 2D matrix with logic values (0 = black, 1 = white).

Comment: Yes, it is OK, just adding info, in case you did not know.

Comment: Oh, ok, I had figured that out, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to scramble matrix M:

```
r = rand(size(M));
[~,ri] = sort(r(:));
M(ri) = M;
```

Comment: THANKS! I used this code without even having to convert it into a 3D RGB matrix and saved it as image and it does EXACTLY what I need. Thanks a lot! (I'd upvote your reply but I'm a new user and it doesn't allow me.)

Comment: Ok, turns out I have to scramble blocks of pixels, not pixels (see my EDIT 4 above). Is there a way to do that with the code you provided? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I should have solved it by using this function: https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56160-hio-been-hb-imagescramble

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to go from grayscale to RGB might be this:

```
rgbImage = cat(3, grayImage, grayImage, grayImage);
```

Then apply your function from FEX and extract one color channel, assuming that the FEX function will yield three identical color channels.

Comment: `repmat` would simpler. But that doesn't convert the logical array to `uint8`, as expected by the FEX function.

Comment: Hi. I used your suggestion and embedded it with some modifications, see my **EDIT 2** in the OP to see what happened.

Comment: @CrisLuengo To solve that problem I used a loop that assigns the correct RGB uint8 value to the logical value, but I found a problem in the function used to scramble.